# Treemap: conditional formatting

Tags: looker-studio

**1) Data**
I have a following dataset in [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17N9WdFPsicYmzUbdAr6gTx-CsfmZ4Qmx0KxCTDzMl7Y/edit?usp=sharing)

| INITIATIVE | ACTUAL SAVING | BUDGET SAVING | DELTA SAVING | ABOVE BUDGET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Initiative_1 | 180 | 200 | -10.0% | 0 |
| Initiative_2 | 80 | 90 | -11.1% | 0 |
| Initiative_3 | 80 | 50 | 60.0% | 1 |
| Initiative_4 | 40 | 20 | 100.0% | 1 |
| Initiative_5 | 20 | 25 | -20.0% | 0 |

**2) Expected output table**

I would like to create a following treemap based on the success of the initiative. If it's above budget, then make it green. If it's below budget, then make it red. (or you can have any in-between colors, i don't mind, based on percentages).

[image: desired output]

**3) Chart: Configuration + Setup**

I have a treemap with default settings.
[setup1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWyle.png)
[setup2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Rkv.png)

**4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output** and **5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4.**

[In my Google Data Studio / Looker](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d87229be-185b-441d-b1c9-f44ee0c03cf2) unfortunately I managed only to build a simple treemap. I failed to find any conditional formatting options. Perhaps there's a way with some community visualisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not wholesome but you could use some workaround on similar lines. In the style pane set max to green and min to red[image]

Comment: Hey thanks. Unfortunately it does not reflect the true size of initiative. In my case initiative1 should be the biggest block on the treemap